# Gelman and Hill's Data on Effects of Child Support Enforcement

Tags: data-request, public-economics, law

In Gelman and Hill's 2007 book, [Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X), chapter 11 begins the exploration of multilevel models. To do so, they introduce a data set that relates city level child support enforcement policies to individual outcomes. Because the treatment is at the city level, this serves to show how sometimes it is good to model the city level effects (at the higher level of the hieratchical model) and then model those as having effects on individuals (the lower level). I'd like to follow along but the data set doesn't seem to be in either of the two places on Gelman's website where he keeps data:

1. [Data and software for the examples in the book](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/)
2. [More data and software for the examples in the book. (Sorry we're a bit disorganized right now!)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/)

Anyone know where to find these data?

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem and found the solution:

Use this code in R:

## input Stata file

library(foreign) 
child <- read.dta("C:\child.iq.dta")

Code found here:(https://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html)

You need the double " \ " if you're using R. 
read.dta("    ") Type the exact folder with data ending. Be careful to use common characters, otherwise R could have problems finding the folder. In my case I just saved the files on C:\.

This way you can access all Data.

I'm using the latest R-Studio version.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: You'll not find the complete data in the files "child.iq.dta" nor "kidiq.dta".

Gelman and Hill say in the book (p.248): "The child support example comes from Nepomnyaschy and Garﬁnkel (2005)."

In that paper they say: "For a detailed description of the FF study design, see Reichman, Teitler, Garﬁnkel, and McLana-
han (2001)."

Finally I found this on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_Families_and_Child_Wellbeing_Study

where's a link to https://opr.princeton.edu/, where you can register and they may send you the data.